# CakePHP : Incrementing correctly based on last value in DB table (check for correct number base)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

In a nutshell, I'm making a booking app. Booking id needs to start at 10000 and increase by one each new booking.

I've started coding a method to generate this booking number. What I'm struggling with is:

1. On first run, there will be no booking numbers so I can't simply add 1 to the last id in the database table. I need a way to check if the last number does in fact have a base of 10000.

I'm using cake php and the way I'm getting the id number is using

```
$ids = $this->find('first', array('order' => 'Booking.id DESC', 'fields' => 'Booking.id'));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either re-create the `Booking` table or alter it so that the `id` field starts at 10000.

Re-Create:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Booking;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Booking (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    /* Other fields here */
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

Or Alter:

```
ALTER TABLE Booking AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

You would only have to do this once.  Afterward, you could be a lot more sure that the last Booking id was 10000 or greater.

Comment: Hmmm. So does this auto increment the table with each new addition? Because I'd rather it didn't. I'd like to create that booking id programmatically... and insert as a field. For control reasons in my application

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute on ID just means that a default value of `MAX(id) + 1` will be used if you don't provide a value for it in rows newly inserted into `Booking`.  There's nothing preventing you from fully controlling the value for id and supplying a value for it each time you create a new Booking.

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify.